# Как добавить модификатор const к псевдониму указателя? С++

Tags: c++, указатели, typedef, using

Возьмем псевдоним для `unsigned char*`, определенный в std как `PBYTE`. Допустим, я хочу получить указатель типа `const unsigned char*`, но поскольку писать все это не самая лучшая идея, я попытался сделать что-то вроде `const PBYTE`. И у меня ничего не получилось. Как я понял, компилятор разворачивает `const PBYTE` в конструкцию типа `unsigned char* const`. То есть константный указатель на неконстантное значение, что диаметрально противоположно нужному типу. Так как получить `const unsigned char*`, если `const PBYTE` не работает, а свой псевдоним вводить не хочется?

Comment: `PBYTE` в `std` всё же нет. В WinAPI есть. Но если это WinAPI, то там есть и `BYTE`, а стало быть можно использовать `const BYTE*`.

Answer (score 6):

```
::std::remove_pointer<PBYTE>::type const *
```

Comment: То есть способа сделать это лаконично прямо в аргументах шаблона нет, нужно либо писать вот это все, либо делать свой псевдоним?

Comment: @ComeInRage Этот способ позволяет писать прямо в аргументах шаблона.

Comment: Я это понимаю прекрасно. Вы меня не поняли.